# What is correct way for unit testing WebApi POST request?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, moq

In common all my test running well, excepting one that testing POST request. Its always return BadRequest. I don't know what is wrong exactly because somehow it's not firing levels below (eg Service layer and Data Layer).
Here is test method:

```
[TestMethod]
        public async Task AddTourObject()
        {
            // Упорядочение
            var mockService = new Mock<ITourObjectService>(MockBehavior.Default);
            var viewmodel = new TourObjectViewModel
            {
                TypeId = 10,
                Name = "Деревья гнулись",
                Address = "f yjxr",
                Latitude = 120.22,
                Longitude = 220.34,
                CountryId = 1,
                RegionId = 2,
                CityId = 1,
                Rating = 2,
                InternalRating = 2,
                CheckInTime = "12:00",
                CheckOutTime = "12:00",
                HowToGet = "sss",
                Web = "web",
                Email = "аааааа"
            };
            mockService.Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<TourObjectDTO>())).ReturnsAsync(new ActionAnswer { });
            var controller = new TourObjectController(mockService.Object);
            // Действие
            var result = await controller.Post(viewmodel);
            // Утверждение
            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(OkNegotiatedContentResult<string>));
            Assert.IsTrue(result.ToString().Contains("успешно"));
        }
```

And method under test:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(TourObjectViewModel viewmodel)
        {
            var answer = new ActionAnswer();
            try
            {
                var dto = new TourObjectDTO
                {
                    TypeId = viewmodel.TypeId,
                    Name = viewmodel.Name,
                    Address = viewmodel.Address,
                    Latitude = viewmodel.Latitude,
                    Longitude = viewmodel.Longitude,
                    CountryId = viewmodel.CountryId,
                    RegionId = viewmodel.RegionId,
                    CityId = viewmodel.CityId.Value,
                    Rating = viewmodel.Rating,
                    InternalRating = viewmodel.InternalRating,
                    CheckInTime = viewmodel.CheckInTime,
                    CheckOutTime = viewmodel.CheckOutTime,
                    HowToGet = viewmodel.HowToGet,
                    Web = viewmodel.Web,
                    Email = viewmodel.Email
                };
                answer = await _tos.Add(dto);
                return answer.IsSuccess == false ? (IHttpActionResult) BadRequest(answer.ToString()) : Ok(answer.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.ErrorFormat("Method:{0} <br/> Error: {1}", System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex);
                return BadRequest(answer.ToString());              
            }
        }
```

1. Am I set up this test correctly?
2. Is this what should I test?

Comment: How will ActionAnswer { } initialize IsSuccess? I would expect `false` which mean that controller return `BadRequest`

Comment: @Lepijohnny, normally method in level below (Service Layer), return ActionAnswer method and set IsSuccess enum to be false or true.

Comment: @Lepijohnny, probably I don't understand how Moq working. Before, I suppose that it's firing full cycle - WebApi > Service > DataAccessLayer.

Comment: Your service will return empty `ActionAnswer` what ever you provide to it. You can try to return `ActionAnswer { IsSuccess = true }`. Inform me if that helped you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your setup here. You setup of the service will return empty `ActionAnswer` for every provided input.

`mockService.Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<TourObjectDTO>())).ReturnsAsync(new ActionAnswer{})`

This mean what ever is provided to service just return empty object. The idea of the mock is to try to simulate different behavior and different paths in your program. So you can for example test following scenarios:

1) what if service returns ActionAnswer with IsSuccess==false
`mockService.Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<TourObjectDTO>())).ReturnsAsync(new ActionAnswer{ IsSuccess = false })`

2) what if service returns ActionAnswer with IsSuccess==true
`mockService.Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<TourObjectDTO>())).ReturnsAsync(new ActionAnswer{ IsSuccess = true })`

There is a plenty of the paths you can choose but idea is to find critical paths and test these.